# vscode auto parentheses not working some cases, can i write some words by a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

It's hard for me to press the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> and then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> when I need parentheses.

I want when I type `print` and press tab or enter then be converted to `print()`
or when I am defining or calling a function.
But this doesn't happen. I tried with python extension, pylance and tabnine (free version).
Maybe you would suggest a user snippet but they are not very pleasant in this way.
I mean if I create a snippet with `pa` key and `()` body,
I must first write `print pa` to be converted to `print ()` and then I must remove space in middle.

It would be great if there was a way to write a few words just by a shortcut.
For example, <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> become to `()`

P.S. English is not my first language, sorry if there are grammatical mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+enter",               // whatever keybinding you like
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "()"
  }
},
```

That is a keybinding fro your `keybindings.json` file.

This does the same:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+enter",
  "command": "type",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "text": "()"
 }
},
```

also a keybinding for the keybindings.json file.